# jest mock returns empty error object when using mockRejectedValue

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking

I'm running a Typescript project with React. In that project I have a class/method that can throw an error that is declared as a dedicated class:

```
class MyCustomError {
    constructor(public details : string[])
} 

class MyClass {
    async doSomething(): Promise<string> {
       // returns Promise.reject(new MyCustomError("foo", "bar"))
       // under some conditions
    }
}
```

This method is consumed as follows:

```
myInstance
     .doSomething()
     .then(() => {
         // something useful here
     })
     .catch((error) => {
         if (error instanceof MyCustomError) {
             console.log(">>"+JSON.stringify(error))
         } else {
             throw error
         }
})
```

Everything works perfectly fine when I run the application! I can catch the custom error and I can access the details collection. No problems everything as expected!
But when I mock MyClass in a test doing like so:

```
mockedApi.sendEvents.mockRejectedValue(new MyCustomError(["foo", "bar"]))
```

then I get into the catch path of the consumer but the error object is empty and I can't access the details property of the error object and console.log(">>"+JSON.stringify(error)) returns '{}'.

Any thoughts about that?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. Both of the classes where declared in the same module:

```
MyModule:

class MyCustomError {
    constructor(public details : string[])
} 

class MyClass {
    async doSomething(): Promise<string> {
       // returns Promise.reject(new MyCustomError("foo", "bar"))
       // under some conditions
    }
}
```

In my test I was mocking the whole module like:

```
jest.mock("../../MyModule")
```

I guess this also created a mock of the MyCustomError class which messed thinks up.